# gstreamer1.0-vaapi can't find driver

Tags: video, qt, gpu-driver, gstreamer, vaapi

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 Server when I try to launch video in Qt Quick based graphical application (`eglfs` backend (EGL full screen)) the video begin to twitch (became choppy, jerky, don't know right word). On previous installation video played smoothly. I make a diff of a trees of `*.so` loaded during video playing for old and new installation. There is not difference. I made an conjecture, that the problem maybe in hardware acceleration.

After I installed the `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` packet and restart the application it hangs if I push "play" button. The log contains the following messages:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
debug qml: Error: 1 (Could not initialize supporting library.) (qrc:///qml/imports/FileManager/components/VideoPlayer.qml:41)
warning default: Error: "Could not initialize supporting library." (unknown:0)
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium

error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
debug qml: Error: 1 (Could not initialize supporting library.) (qrc:///qml/imports/FileManager/components/VideoPlayer.qml:41)
warning default: Error: "Could not initialize supporting library." (unknown:0)
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
```

Then I type:

```
# apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
mesa-va-drivers: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
# apt install mesa-va-drivers
# ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so': No such file or directory
```

How is it possible? There is evidence, that package `mesa-va-drivers` should contain that `*.so` file. No other package did. Should I build mesa va drivers by myself?

Both old and new systems have the following configuration: AMD A10-7800 Radeon R7, 12 Compute Cores 4C+8G.

`vainfo`:

```
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Comment: I would not rely on `apt-file` like this -  run `apt-file update` before the search ! Maybe try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mesa-va-drivers`?

Comment: Surely bases of `apt-file` are updated to be recent. Also I tried to `apt-get --reinstall install` more then one time.

Comment: Maybe problem not in driver. Because it turns out, that on the old system there is also no that `*.so`. Therefore problem is splitted into the two separate independent ones.

Comment: Interesting... I had a look into the deb package of `mesa-va-drivers`  and the `gallium_drv_video.so` **is** there...

Comment: `locate _drv_video.so` lists only `dummy`, `i965`, `nvidia`, `s3g` and `vdpau` drivers. [Arch docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration#Configuring_VA-API) says, that `Since version 12.0.1 libva-mesa-driver provides radeonsi instead of gallium.`. Invocation in form `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=radeonsi vainfo` works fine.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mesa-va-drivers` ? **arch =! ubuntu !!** While Arch WIki often provides great tutorials, the packages of the OS  are not the same !

Comment: @RobertRiedl Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did just have this exact same thing.  Yes, @RobertRiedl comment about where the `gallium_drv_video.so` is correct.  However, it is not listed as that as it is only a link to another file.

To fix it I did the following:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/
sudo rm gallium_drv_video.so
sudo apt install mesa_va_drivers
sudo ln -s radeonsi_drv_video.so gallium_drv_video.so
```

After running the above, then checking the vainfo worked fine:

To correct the can't connect to the X server run:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xhost +
```

Running `vainfo` to make sure it is working:

```
:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.1)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 18.1.0-devel for AMD RS880 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-36-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

Hope this helps!