# VLC keeps crashing immediately when opening a movie

Tags: vlc

Here is the logs that it does when I open it from the command line. It only crashes when I try to watch a movie

```
Gtk-Message: 14:37:51.041: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
: CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Comment: This happens when there is a problem with the video card driver. Try the opensource/closed source when you are using the closed source/open source version.

Comment: Open up vlc > Tools > Preferences > Input/Codecs & in the dropdown for hardware-accelerated decoding choose `Disable`. Then click save & all should be ok. Most vids don't need hardware acceleration

Comment: It might be failing on the `radeonsi_drv_video.so`.  I wonder if this answer might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1009396/231142

Comment: I can't understand how to change my drivers? I am new and I have looked up this and only found links to older versions of Ubuntu. When I CD'd to /etc/X11/ there is no xorg.conf?